# Phusion Passenger installation error in MacOS 10.13 High Sierra

Tags: ruby, nginx, passenger, macos-sierra

I've been trying to install Phusion Passenger under macOS X 10.13 High Sierra using the method mentioned here. https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/nginx/install/oss/osx/

Getting the following response. Does anyone have any insight into this issue and/or any suggestions to help me fix this?

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ranlib: file:
buildout/apache2/module_libboost_oxt.a(regex_debug.o) has no symbols
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ranlib: file:
buildout/apache2/module_libboost_oxt.a(tss_null.o) has no symbols
clang -o buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.o  -Isrc/agent
-Isrc/cxx_supportlib -Isrc/cxx_supportlib/vendor-copy -Isrc/cxx_supportlib/vendor-modified -fPIC -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/include -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fvisibility=hidden -DVISIBILITY_ATTRIBUTE_SUPPORTED -g -DHAS_ALLOCA_H -DHAS_SFENCE -DHAS_LFENCE -DPASSENGER_DEBUG -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS -c src/apache2_module/mod_passenger.c
src/apache2_module/mod_passenger.c:26:10: fatal error: 'httpd.h' file
not found
#include <httpd.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~ 1 error generated. rake aborted! Command failed with status (1): [clang -o buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.o 
-Isrc/agent -Isrc/cxx_supportlib -Isrc/cxx_supportlib/vendor-copy -Isrc/cxx_supportlib/vendor-modified -fPIC -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/include -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fvisibility=hidden -DVISIBILITY_ATTRIBUTE_SUPPORTED -g -DHAS_ALLOCA_H -DHAS_SFENCE -DHAS_LFENCE -DPASSENGER_DEBUG -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS -c src/apache2_module/mod_passenger.c]


/private/tmp/passenger-20171008-7392-owxt2w/passenger-5.1.8/build/support/cplusplus.rb:53:in `run_compiler'
/private/tmp/passenger-20171008-7392-owxt2w/passenger-5.1.8/build/support/cplusplus.rb:97:in `compile_c'
/private/tmp/passenger-20171008-7392-owxt2w/passenger-5.1.8/build/support/cplusplus.rb:154:in
`block in define_c_object_compilation_task' Tasks: TOP => apache2 =>
buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so => buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.o
```

Comment: Check if `/usr/include/apache2/httpd.h` file exists on your mac?

Answer (score 1):

Compilation fixes for macOS High Sierra were recently [added to Passenger's stable branch](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/commit/416894542e3c689f4d609e6ce7f6c9a298ca3992) and will be part of release 5.1.11.

Comment: Thanks for the response.